# How to find user name and password for PostgresSQL on mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos

How to find user name and password for PostgresSQL on mac? I did not remember that I have set a password and username. How to find the default username and password on mac?

Comment: I don't think there's a universal "default" account; it depends on how you installed PostgreSQL. Postgresql.app is probably different from a Homebrew install which is different from a from-source install, etc. How *did* you install it? Also, notice that PostgreSQL can be configured (in pg_hba.conf) to trust all local connections. If you do that, there's a decent chance that you can connect as postgres, _postgres or your unix username, without a password.

Comment: I update my answer that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To log in without a password:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

To know the username

```sql
\du
```

To reset the password:

```sql
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

replace `user_name` with your username you found by `\du` command

Comment: Is sudo really needed?

Comment: @OneCricketeer sure.

Comment: But this depends on how it was installed. `psql` shouldn't require root permissions, so `su postgres` alone would switch a user account.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes your right, but before I update my answer It was like `sudo -u user_name psql db_name`, so `user_name` means the username he wants to change his forgotten password, and it will access this user without a password, since he not know the username too I updated just the `user_name` to Postgres and `db_name` to
Postgres, and also your solution will work without the `sudo` command.